# I want to dynamically create new instances of a Vue component with information attached to each of them. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

What I want to do:

- I have multiple select elements
- Each time I pick an option out of them, that option is added to an array of keywords
- Each keyword will be displayed in a "tag" component
- Each of these tags can be removed as well, which will unset my list of keywords

Note: this is bound with Laravel and Blade templates, hence the @ preceding the mustache syntax.

**Template**

```
<select @change="switchType">
    <option v-for="type in types" value="@{{ type.value }}">@{{ type.text }}</option> 
</select>

...

<tag v-for="keyword in keywords" model="@{{ keyword.model }}" identifier="@{{ keyword.id }}" text="@{{ keyword.text }}"></tag>
```

**JS**

```
const API_TYPES = '/api/types';

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '.search',
    data: {
        types: [],
        type: null,
        keywords: [],
    },

    ready: function() {
        this.$http.get(API_TYPES).then(function(types) {
            this.$set('types', types.body)
        });
    },

    methods: {
        search: function() {
            if (this.type) {
                this.keywords.push({
                    model: 'type',
                    identifier: this.type.id,
                    text: this.type.name
                })
            }
        },

        switchType: function(event) {
            var self = this
            var value = event.target.value
            console.log(value)
            this.$set('type', {id: value, name: event.target[value].text})
            self.search()
        },
    },

    components: {
        'tag': {
            template: `
                <span class="tag is-warning is-medium">
                    {{ model }} {{ identifier }} {{ text }}
                    <button class="delete is-small" @click="removeTag"></button>
                </span>
            `,
            props: [
                'model',
                'identifier',
                'text'
            ],
            methods: {
                removeTag: function () {
                    this.$el.remove()
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

In short: I want to do [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTwL7.jpg) but the yellow pill item doesn't get its data sent, despite being created properly.

What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty new to this data-centric approach so let me know if you find some inconsistencies with my code. Thanks!

Comment: The latest version, 2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of what you are doing is `Vue 1` syntax, but you are using `Vue 2`, so firstly:

The `ready()` lifecycle hook has been deprecated, and you now use `created()`:

```
created: function() {
    this.$http.get(API_TYPES).then(function(types) {
        this.$set('types', types.body)
    });
}
```

`Interpolation` inside attributes has also been removed, essentially you cannot use handlebars (or need to) when assigning model data to an attribute (it's still fine in HTML), so, you should remove the handlebars for `value` and use `v-bind` instead (you can also just use a colon as a shorthand for `v-bind` e.g. `:value="type.value"`):

```
<select @change="switchType">
    <option v-for="type in types" v-bind:value="type.value">@{{ type.text }}</option> 
</select>
```

I personally would bind my select boxes using `v-model`, rather than trying to manually handle the change, but without seeing your entire project, I couldn't say for sure that this would be appropriate for your project, but basically you bind each `select box` to an element of an array:

**Markup**

```
  <select v-model="selected[0]">
    <option v-for="type in types" v-bind:value="type.value" v-text="type.text"></option>
  </select>
  
    <select v-model="selected[1]">
    <option v-for="type in types" v-bind:value="type.value" v-text="type.text"></option>
  </select>
```

**View Model:**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    types: [{
      value: 'foo',
      text: 'foo'
    }, {
      value: 'bar',
      text: 'bar'
    }, {
      value: 'baz',
      text: 'baz'
    }],
    selected: []
  }
})
```

And if you wanted to do something when the selection changes you could just add a watcher to that:

```
  watch: {
    selected: function(val){
      // do something
      console.log('selected updated to: ' + val);
    }
  }
```

Here's the JSFiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/utf169mw/

If you get stuck on anything else `Vue` has a migration guide at: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html

You can find the `2.0` docs at: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/

And of course you can ask here, also remember to check your `console` under your browsers `developer tools`, because `Vue` will generally tell you what the problem is.